# (-2003F) Macbook keeps booting into Internet Recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, recovery

Recently I've wiped a 2020 MacBook Pro and now it keeps booting into Internet Recovery; trying to proceed results in a -2003F error. Additionally, it's now impossible to turn the MacBook off; once I hold the Power button down, it keeps booting up on its own.

I tried using multiple WiFi networks, but no luck. Using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't do anything.

Comment: When you say 'wiped': what did you do exactly? Delete all the containers and APFS structure, or just erase the Data volume? If you haven't got another Mac that you can use to install the OS via Target mode, or use Apple Configurator app, then I'd recommend taking it to an Apple Store.

Comment: Use a wired connection. Precisely which MacBook? The M1 doesn't use the same key commands as the old Intel.